# I hovered over a p but all p changed background what did I do wrong here?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover, css-selectors

I have two links and both inside a paragraph and somehow when I hover over one link both paragraph changes background.

What have I done wrong? Or it's not even the way to do it that I should just use all anchor tag and use display: block in css instead...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/859d8/)

I have these for my html

```
<nav>
<p><a href="">Home</a></p>
<p><a href="">Contact</a></p>
</nav>
```

I have this for my css

```
nav {
    width: 100px;
}

nav p {
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#503520, #7F5C40, #503520); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#503520, #7F5C40, #503520); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#503520, #7F5C40, #503520); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#503520, #7F5C40, #503520); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav a:link, nav a:visited {
    color: #F3BB02;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover, nav a:active{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav:hover p {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A); 
    background: linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, it should be...

```
nav p:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A); 
    background: linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3E4Pw/)

Explanation: Using `nav:hover p` means target all `p` elements nested inside `nav` on `:hover` so change it to `nav p:hover` so it means target `p` element on `:hover` which are nested under `nav`

---

Suggestion: You should use `ul` and `li` elements for making a navigation menu and not `p` element, and than use `display: inline-block` for your `li` or you can `float` them as well if you want them *inline* and if you don't than just leave them as is. Also note, that if you are using `float` than **don't forget** to *clear your floats* if you use `float`.

---

Further moving on with your code, you have set `nav` to `100px` but your nested `a` is set to `180px` which is anyways redundant, so instead, use `180px` for `nav` and get rid of `180px` from `a` element, also, you would like to assign `height` and `width` to `a` instead of `p` as if you don't, than user will have ONLY `a` text as clickable, which is bad from UI point of view, so I've tweaked your code ahead in this demo, also make sure you turn your `a` element to `display: block;`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/3E4Pw/1/)

**CSS For Demo 2**

```
nav {
    width: 180px;
}

nav p {    
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#503520, #7F5C40, #503520); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#503520, #7F5C40, #503520); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#503520, #7F5C40, #503520); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#503520, #7F5C40, #503520); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
}

nav a:link, nav a:visited {
    color: #F3BB02;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover, nav a:active{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav p:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A); 
    background: linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A);
}
```

Comment: ah! Thanks for all the suggestions no wonder I feel like I'm doing something wrong and totally get what you mean by the width of nav and p. guess I still need lots experiences to get things smooth.

Answer (score 1):

```
you are targeting all p's which is wrong target one p after hover :) 

nav:p:hover {

}
```

below is your code with one word("p"   :P) moved only

http://jsfiddle.net/wLb28/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[Check fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/859d8/2/)

As i seen in your code i got hover selector is wrong, it should be like this..

```
nav p:hover {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A); 
    background: linear-gradient(#89776A, #7F5C40, #89776A);
}
```